# Can Powershell Give Me Information on the Server's Certificate Used By Invoke-WebRequest?

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

For instance, in Powershell 4,

```
$StackExAPIResponse = Invoke-WebRequest https://api.stackexchange.com/users/104624?site=serverfault -TimeoutSec 3 -ErrorAction Stop
```

That command works perfectly well, but, is there any way for me to also get the information about the SSL certificate used in that request, such as hash algorithm, expiration date, etc.?

Edit: I'd also accept something with `Invoke-RestMethod`, etc...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The PowerShell cmdlets don't have a native way to do this.  You will probably have to drop down to the .Net libraries if you want certificate information.

One way of doing this will involve using the `System.Net.ServicePointManager` class. In specific, the `FindServicePoint` method.

This will have to be done as a separate operation from the `Invoke-WebRequest`.
See the MSDN documenation for the [method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5f0atwd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and the [return value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepoint%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more details about what you can do, but the following would give you the data you specifically mentioned.  One thing to note: I noticed that when I tried calling `FindServicePoint` prior to actually calling `Invoke-WebRequest` or `Invoke-RestMethod`, the `Certificate` property on the service point was null.

```
$StackExAPIResponse = Invoke-WebRequest https://api.stackexchange.com/users/104624?site=serverfault -TimeoutSec 3 -ErrorAction Stop
$servicePoint = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::FindServicePoint("https://api.stackexchange.com")
$servicePoint.Certificate.GetCertHashString()
$servicePoint.Certificate.GetExpirationDateString()
```

Comment: This looks promising for a script that I'm trying to write for reading information about an endpoint's certificate via PowerShell. Unfortunately, the returned ServicePoint comes up with empty Certificate properties when I test. Any thoughts as to why?

Comment: Did you figure out why it isn't working?  I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. Eventually I determined Invoke-WebRequest was returning a parsing error related to Internet Explorer. I was running the script on server where Internet Explorer was not installed. Check out this thread: The response content cannot be parsed because the Internet Explorer engine is not available, or Internet Explorer's first-launch configuration is not complete. After adding -UseBasicParsing to the command, the script started working. `$servicePoint.Certificate.GetExpirationDateString()` was no longer null.