# Trying to get Certificate Information in Powershell

Tags: powershell, certificate

I recently posted some code here : [Powershell hanging in script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57561989/powershell-hanging-in-script?noredirect=1#comment101587241_57561989)

And someone recommended using Invoke-WebRequest instead of the way I was getting the cert information to make it clean and short.

I was able to get the Invoke-WebRequest to work but can't figure out how to get the cert information.

I found this link : [Can Powershell Give Me Information on the Server's Certificate Used By Invoke-WebRequest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20012982/can-powershell-give-me-information-on-the-servers-certificate-used-by-invoke-we)

But this does not seem to be working for me. What am I doing wrong?

```
$url = "https://google.com"
$req = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Proxy $proxy -ProxyUseDefaultCredentials
$servicepoint = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::FindServicePoint($url)
$servicepoint.Certificate.GetExpirationDateString()
$servicepoint.Certificate.Subject
$servicepoint.Certificate.Issuer
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:5 char:1
+ $servicepoint.Certificate.GetExpirationDateString()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

I also tried to do it exactly as the test and not use the $url variable and instead type it in, and received the same error.

```
$req = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://google.com -Proxy $proxy -ProxyUseDefaultCredentials
$servicepoint = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::FindServicePoint("https://google.com")
$servicepoint.Certificate.GetExpirationDateString()
$servicepoint.Certificate.Subject
$servicepoint.Certificate.Issuer
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:4 char:1
+ $servicepoint.Certificate.GetExpirationDateString()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Comment: I am unable to replicate the issue. Could this be a problem with your proxy?

Comment: @TheMadTechnician That’s what I am thinking. It works fine in the first link to my longer more convoluted code. But here it does not. I wonder if there is a work around?

Comment: There's a constructor for the `FindServicePoint` method that includes proxy information. You should look into that.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician are you referring to : System.Net.IWebProxy ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager.findservicepoint?view=netframework-4.8

sorry, I am very new so just want to make sure I'm heading down the right road for your suggestion

Comment: Yeah, that's the one. I haven't looked into it, so I'm not sure how to instantiate an instance of it, but there's got to be a way. I'm guessing that'll fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

the error says that line 4 is null.
i am doing the same .
for subject \ cert name i am calling like so.
$certName = $servicePoint.Certificate.GetName()
i hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. Eventually I determined Invoke-WebRequest was returning a parsing error related to Internet Explorer. I was running the script on server where Internet Explorer was not installed. Check out this thread: [The response content cannot be parsed because the Internet Explorer engine is not available, or Internet Explorer's first-launch configuration is not complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38005341/the-response-content-cannot-be-parsed-because-the-internet-explorer-engine-is-no). After adding -UseBasicParsing to the command, the script started working. $servicePoint.Certificate.GetExpirationDateString() was no longer null.